# ShouldAutorotate and GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations not called in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, rotation, xamarin

I made a UIViewController like

```
public class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    ...

    public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
    }
}
```

and use it in AppDelegate.cs.

```
Window.RootViewController = new MyViewController();
```

When I run this code, "ShouldAutorotate" and "GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations" are called many times in view initializing phase, but after application view shown, they never called again.

I checked that orientation setting in Info.plist is valid.
iOS SDK Target is 7.1, Xamarin Studio Version is 5.0.1 (build 3) and Xamarin.iOS Version is 7.2.3.39.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

iOS checks these as the views loads and caches the answer for use during display.

Comment: how do we fix it then?